# How to save a variable or text to use for view counts or counter?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a view counts or counter, like in Youtube. Views = 23. After researching I got the code that can add views, I click an image or a button and I can increment the view counts, (23, 24, 25 and so forth )
But when I reload the page. I get 0 again.

Using some php I can write to a file, and I can write anything. The problem I have is that I don't know how to save the file, so I can save the views. So when I reload the page I still have the views I had before.

This is my code

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  <?php
  $handle = fopen ( 'counterViews.txt', 'w');
  fwrite($handle, '0');
  fclose ($handle);
  echo 'var';
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var count = 0;
      function changevar(){
              count = count + 1;
          document.getElementById("viewCount").textContent = count;
       }
   </script>
  <button onclick="changevar()">Click here to count views</button>
  <p>Views: <span id="viewCount">0</span></p>
    <a href="http://songnes.com/ID00049_Bye_Bye_Love.html"><img src="http://songnes.com/images/mainBanner.jpg" alt="Main Banner For   Songnes" id="banner" style='width:100%;' border="0" onclick="changevar()">.    </a>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Comment: You're writing 0 to the text file every time the page loads.  Then you're ignoring the text file logic altogether and adding the count logic to javascript.  Javascript is transient between page refreshes.

Comment: `fwrite($handle, '0');` You are writing **0** every thime you write to the file ..  You need a variable here and to add 1 to it every time the file is opened ..  Conversely, if the file is "open" while another page check is "trying" to open it and write to it at the same time, your count will be skewed.  I recommend using a database to store this, but that's just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The pure PHP text solution with explanations in commented code:

```
<?php 

$fp = fopen("counterViews.txt", "r"); // Open the file for reading 

$count = fread($fp, 1024); // Get the existing count 

fclose($fp); // Close the file 

$count++; // This acts like "$count = $count + 1" -- Just adding 1 to $count

$fp = fopen("counterViews.txt", "w"); //Open the file again, for WRITING this time

fwrite($fp, $count); // Write the new count to the file 

fclose($fp); // Close the file 

?>
```

Though as I said in my comment .. There are reasons this **should** be done with a database..

**EDIT**
After reading your post further --  You are in need of an AJAX solution.

Create this file -- And name it **counter.php**

```
<?php 
$fp = fopen("counterViews.txt", "r"); // Open the file for reading 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); // Get the existing count 
fclose($fp); // Close the file 
$count++; // This acts like "$count = $count + 1" -- Just adding 1 to $count
$fp = fopen("counterViews.txt", "w"); //Open the file again, for WRITING this time
fwrite($fp, $count); // Write the new count to the file 
fclose($fp); // Close the file 
echo $count; // Output to update the views live
?>
```

Then your page with the Javascript on it name this **index.html** --  It is important to notice I included the jQuery library.:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

  <button onclick="changevar()">Click here to count views</button>
   <?php
      $fp = fopen("counterViews.txt", "r"); // Open the file for reading 
      $count = fread($fp, 1024); // Get the existing count
      fclose($fp);
    ?>

  <p>Views: <span id="viewCount"><?php echo $count; ?></span></p>
    <a href="http://songnes.com/ID00049_Bye_Bye_Love.html"><img src="http://songnes.com/images/mainBanner.jpg" alt="Main Banner For   Songnes" id="banner" style='width:100%;' border="0" onclick="changevar()">.    </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var count = 0;
      function changevar(){
              $.post("counter.php", {update: 'update'}, function(result){
    $("#viewCount").html(result);
});
       }
   </script>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative **without** need of **clicking** in button.
The JS code uses the **setInterval** function.
The setInterval function executes any code in each interval of milliseconds.
The code executed this time is an Ajax request and its result is the number of views (pages loaded), after this value is placed in the value of the input text counter.
The PHP code considers the existence of the file in the **first** global visit to index.php (visit =1) where in later visits, after loading the page, *the counter increments by 1*.

**index.php** :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="your_path_to_jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">           
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'get',
                    url:      'test.php',
                    data:         {},
                    success:  function( response ){
                      // for check views counter
                      console.log("Calling : "+response); 
                      //the views is setted to input #counter
                      $('#counter').val(response); 

                    }
                });
            },2000); //interval of 2 secs
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php        
        $counter=0;
        if (file_exists("counter.txt")){ 
            $fp=fopen("counter.txt",'r');
            $counter = fgets($fp);
            fclose($fp);    
            $counter++;
            //reopen the file for WRITE the updated counter
            $fp=fopen("counter.txt",'w'); 
            fwrite($fp,$counter);
            fclose($fp);    
        } else { 
            //In the first visit, the file not exists,
            $fp=fopen("counter.txt",'w');
            $counter=1;
            fwrite($fp,$counter);
            fclose($fp);    
        }
        //The initial $counter (after loading page )is placed in the input 
        //text with name counter
    ?>

        <input type="text" name="counter" id="counter" value="<?php echo $counter?>"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here the test.php file requested by the Ajax, used **only to read** the number of views saved in the file **counter.txt** :
**test.php**

```
<?php
//Only read the value $counter saved in the file
$counter=0;
if (file_exists("counter.txt")){ 
    $fp=fopen("counter.txt",'r');
    $counter = fgets($fp);    
    fclose($fp);    
} else { 
    $counter=1;    
}
echo $counter;
```

Test executing from two different browsers to see the results.